# How can I open a SQLite database in android?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sqlitemanager

If I created a database using another application not through android runtime, let's say using 'SQLite Manager'(firefox extention), how can I then use that database (the .Sqlite file that is generated) in my android application?

Since the SQLite is native in the android not an outsider database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it by preparing database file(.sqlite) from Sqlite Manager(firefox extention) and then use it in android see [**example**](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/)

Comment: Is there is another way to do it rather that the way described in this tutorial ??

Comment: create database by own Java class, refer http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html